# What is the recommended best practice for C# Workflow using External Activity for Logging and Configuration?

Tags: workflow, configuration, c#, logging

I have a c# workflow using an external activity assembly uploaded into a TBB. Currently I have a logging class to write to a hard coded file path in the DEBUG build. The RWS example documentation does not indicate any configuration or logging options for workflow.

**Configuration**
I was thinking of maybe moving the configuration into a component to make the solution more configurable for Debug and Release builds for Staging and Live environments, are there any other options?

**Logging**
I would like to replace the simple logging class with log4net but can't find a reliable method to reference the external log4net assembly. Merging the log4net assembly does not seem to be recommended, and is complicated. Has anyone integrated log4net or other logging framework into their Tridion workflow solution? Is it possible to reference the log4net assembly if it were uploaded to a TBB?

**Update:**

We are working with SDL Cloud for CMS Hosting and Content Delivery so I am looking for solutions that are deployable with CMS Upload to TBB or using Tridion Addon to deploy to CMS and Publishers.

Comment: For logging, you could consider to use the (semi-public) `Tridion.Logging` API, which is used by the system itself. It's basically an abstraction over some underlying logging mechanism (originally: MS Enterprise Library, nowadays: NLog) and provides a smooth integration with Tridion Event Log.   So far, this API is not considered part of the official public API, but I'm aware of several implementations that use it and given the simplicity of the API, it is not likely to change.

Answer (score 4):

I normally add it GAC on the CM server and on publisher machines. It is so widely used (because it is standard now) that it makes sense to have it there (to be system-wide available).
There are quite a few options for that. The only problem with adding it to GAC (global assembly cache) besides it being loaded every time, is that GAC is version-specific, meaning that you need to take care of which versions of Log4Net you are adding in GAC and which you are using. Plus GAC can be left with numerous versions which are all loaded but nowhere used, so you need to manage it.